# How to have the random function run once in the draw function?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, p5.js

This is the code

```
let x = 10;
let y = 0;
let bottomy = 100;
let Speed = 1

function setup() {

createCanvas(windowWidth,600);
}

function draw() {
 background(0)


 strokeWeight(3)
 stroke(255)


 for (i = 0; i < width; i += 20) {
   water()
   line(i,y,i,bottomy)
}


 bottomy = bottomy + Speed;
 if (bottomy > height) {
 bottomy = 100
 }
 frameRate(1)
 }

 function water(){
 bottomy = random(0,600)
 //noLoop()
 }
```

I want to randomise each y2 line coordinate in the for loop. But then have the y2 line coordinate to increment by 1. To create a rain effect.

I can't put the random variable in setup and then call it in the for loop because it won't affect each line in the for loop and I can't put the for loop in setup because I need the line to be drawn.

I've also tried creating a function that loops once and then calling it in draw but it ends up stopping all the code in the draw function.

I've seen examples where they generate like an infinite amount of random lines. But I would like to keep the x position of each line the same if possible. If it's not possible to do this with a for loop and I have to draw each line individually that's fine I was just wondering if this is possible to efficiently do this with a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is individual variables for each line.
Probably a classic:

[from-several-variables-to-arrays](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/8082/from-several-variables-to-arrays.html)

[from-several-arrays-to-classes](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/8081/from-several-arrays-to-classes.html)

situation. (those were made in Java's processing, but the concept can be easily adapted)

Anyway, i think this is what you tried to make with your code, but it does not work as intended, since you only have one `bottomY` var for all lines.

```js
let x = 10;
let y = 0;
let bottomY = 100;
let spd = 1; //by convention capitalized names are for classes

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, 600);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);

  strokeWeight(3);
  stroke(255);

  for (i = 0; i < width; i += 20) {
    if (bottomY > height) {
      bottomY = random(600);
    }
    line(i, y, i, bottomY);
  }

  bottomY += spd;
}
```

What you want is several lines that each has individual `x` and `bottomY`
So you could use two arrays for that:

```js
let x = [];
let y = 0;
let bottomY = [];
//why not have individual speeds as well...
let spd = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, 600);
  for (i = 0; i < width; i += 20) {
    x.push(i);
    bottomY.push(random(height));
    spd.push(random(0.6, 2));
  }
  strokeWeight(3);
  stroke(255);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);

  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    line(x[i], y, x[i], bottomY[i]);
    if (bottomY[i] < height) {
      bottomY[i] += spd[i];
    } else {
      bottomY[i] = random(height);
    }
  }
}
```

And finally a simple class implementation:

```
let rain = [];
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, 600);
  for (i = 0; i < width; i += 20) {
    rain.push(new Drop(i, 0));
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(0);

  for (const d of rain) {
    d.run();
  }
}

class Drop {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.btY = random(height);
    this.spd = random(0.6, 2);
  }

  run() {
    strokeWeight(3);
    stroke(255);
    line(this.x, this.y, this.x, this.btY);
    if (this.btY < height) {
      this.btY += this.spd;
    } else {
      this.btY = random(height);
    }
  }
} //class
```

Did it make sense?